# Any idea why this is not plotting using ggplot

Tags: python, ggplot2, plotnine

I'm trying to plot a scatter using ggplot but im unable to get it to work, any ideas?

dataframe and packages installed

```
import numpy as np
from plotnine import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#scatter plot
locations = accidents[['Latitude','Longitude']]
locations

Latitude    Longitude
0   51.508057   -0.153842
1   51.436208   -0.127949
```

Code attempted:

```
(ggplot(locations(x = 'Latitude', y = 'Longitude', colour = 'red')) +
geom_point())

Error code;
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/8_/2k6q9p1s4vg_6bqjd8zpqtzm0000gn/T/ipykernel_65786/2478097116.py in. 
<module>
----> 1 (ggplot(locations(x = 'Latitude', y = 'Longitude', colour = 'red')) +
      2     geom_point())

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Comment: Try with `ggplot(locations, aes(x = 'Latitude', y = 'Longitude', colour = 'red'))`. At least that's the way to do it in R and as far as I know the same in plotnine. First argument is the data, the second the mapping.

Comment: The comma after locations was causing the issue, cheers. Although the whole code does still need to be in brackets which is how Python differs to R